# Microphone denial not properly handled on android app

Tags: javascript, android, permissions, microphone, getusermedia

We have a project where try to access the audio permissions from the andriod app where in my JS functions.(Internally App also runs on a browser) I am doing it like this.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).then(function(stream){
// do something with stream
}).catch(function() {
// no media recorder function
})
```

When the user denies the audio permissions it should go to into catch part but it isn't and showing up something like this on the app.(A modal with "OK")

When the android app asks for permissions of microphone, I click on deny, then it should ideally go into catch block but thats not happening and its getting interfered by `GOT IT` alert about which I have no idea about.

The problem I see is when I click on deny, getUserMedia throws errors but it doesn't and the promise still remains in pending state with nothing happening

Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance!!
[image]

Comment: To even possibly help we'd need to see the try block, not just the catch.

Comment: Have added the try block

Comment: Is this with the Chrome browser or the Samsung browser? Please [edit] your question. And, I don't think that `GOT IT` popup is in the browser; is it in some other part of your Javascript? That being said, it's hard to recover from media-permission denial.